# InnoSetup: need to add validate URL by adding test button on CreateInputQueryPage

Tags: inno-setup

I have on CreateInputQueryPage, in that box user will type URL...Now i want to have Test button next to that text box so i can ping and validate that URL...is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Standard Support Functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions), you are unable to do this.

You can [call an external dll](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll), which would allow you to do this.
You can also call [COM interfaces](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptautomation), which would also allow you do to this.

Specifically you could use [WinHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) COM object to perform this check.

You have a couple of options to deal with the validation.   Both are demonstrated in the following script.     The first is to create a button just for validation, the 2nd is to hook the Next Button and have it occur automatically before moving to the next page.

```
[Setup]
AppName='Test Script'
AppVerName='Test Script'
DefaultDirName={pf}\test
[Code]

const
 InputQueryPageID = 100;  //Determined by watching in Debugger.

var
  Page : TInputQueryWizardPage;


procedure ClickEvent(Sender : TObject);
begin
   MsgBox('Could Validate Here',mbInformation,MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Button : TButton; 
begin
  Page := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
     'Add URL', 'Test2','Test3');
  Page.Add('URL:', False);
  Button := TButton.Create(Page);
  Button.Parent := Page.Surface;
  Button.Caption := 'Button Text';
  Button.Top := 100;
  Button.Left := 10;
  Button.OnClick := @ClickEvent;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurrPageID: Integer) : Boolean;
begin
 case CurrPageID of
   InputQueryPageID   : begin
                 MsgBox('Could Validate Here',mbInformation,MB_OK);
                 result := true; // Results of EXE Validation
               end;
   else result := true;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but how do i add a button on CreateInputQueryPage? I am planning to call exteranal exe to validate the URL. Or i cant add a btton on CreateInputQueryPage and i have to use. Parent := KeyPage gives type mismatch error. Code is like                                     
'KeyPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
with TButton.Create(KeyPage) do begin
    Left := ALeft;
    Top := ATop;
    Width := (WizardForm.CancelButton.Width*3)/2;
    Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
    Caption := ACaption;
    OnClick := ANotifyEvent;
    Parent := KeyPage;

Comment: @chirag is KeyPage.Surface that you need to set the buttons parent to.   Updated answer to show working example code.

Comment: Great, thanks for your response. I will try this and pretty sure that it will work.